# Star Shape Python

Tags: python, shapes

I'm trying to recreate this shape (image below) using Python but I have some difficulties with the spaces.

This is the code that I have so far.

```
def shape(n):
    for i in range(0,n):
        for j in range(0,i+1):
            print("*",end="")
        print("")
    for i in range(n,0,-1):
        for j in range(0,i-1):
            print("","*",end="")
        print("")
        
shape(10)
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me.
[image: star shape]

Comment: First of all: This is a space: `" "`. This is an empty string: `""`.

Answer (score -1):

```
def star(width = 10):
    left_start = 0
    right_start = 0
    size = width
    while right_start != size:
        right_start += 1
        print("*" * (right_start - left_start))
    
    while left_start != right_start:
        left_start += 1
        print(" " * left_start + "*" * (right_start - left_start))
```

Hope this helps!